# Android toolbar + actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am using Appcompat library to get the supportActionBar in my ActionBarActivity. Now I am facing another challenge and it's how to add toolbar under that actionbar, something like facebook app has. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe they implement something like a slidingtablayout. Have a look at this link, the Google developers docs have example code for it.

https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html

Answer (score 1):

Once you call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`, you agreed that the `ActionBar` will be replaced with `Toolbar`. I believe that Facebook app uses sliding [Tab](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html), instead of `ActionBar` below `Toolbar`, but they designed it as pretty as possible. Android only allows us to set one `ActionBar`, no more. Think that you override `onCreateOptionsMenu`, where are the `Menu` items will be placed?

Comment: Well, that's true. But how to design that sliding tab ?

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to have

Answer (score 0):

Just add android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar in your layout for that activity but don't call setActionBar(Toolbar) in your onCreate(). The Toolbar can have normal Views inside it, like Button, TextView, etc. which you can get handles of using the usual findViewById().

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/bg_gradient_start"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/toolbarBackButton"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="@string/back"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTitleText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            tools:text="Title" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/toolbarNextButton"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="@string/next"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color" />
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In **activity_main.xml** I have

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

Then in your onCreate() you can just `findViewById(R.id.toolbarBackButton)` or any id you want to use, same as other views.

Comment: This looks promising. Just one question, how can I add those views ? I mean what xml and in java code. I am not very familiar with actionbars

Comment: You mean Toolbars? You know how FrameLayout can have elements inside it? Toolbars can, too.

Comment: I meant all that stuff :D Hmm, So I just nest that in xml or how ? Can you show me please ?